Capture Oracle output as HTML script which can be passed to a web page to show sql output in table format
Here is the Student table and first 5 columns are keys



emplid
Event
Career
CAR_NBR
CATALOG_NBR
ACAD_PROG
STRM
TERM_DESCR30
COURSE_TITLE
UNT_TAKEN




100
699
PGRD
0
73A
57
410
Trimester 1 2024
Title-1
10


100
699
PGRD
0
74N
57
410
Trimester 1 2024
Title-2
10


100
699
PGRD
0
79N
57
410
Trimester 1 2024
Title-3
20


200
280
PGRD
2
71A
32
410
Trimester 1 2024
Title-4
10



Now I need to prepare a sql view which gives me the output in HTML format(one field- HTML String).
In down stream people uses this sql view's output to any webpage to show the result in a table format.
expected outcome would be like below:
|EMPLID |EVENT_NBR| CAREER| STDNT_CAR_NBR   |HTML String
| -------- | -------- |--------|------| -------- | 
|100    |699    |PGRD   |0  |
|200    |280    |PGRD   |2  |

Here the HTML String should represent data in a table format with fields CATALOG_NBR,  TERM_DESCR30,COURSE_TITLE , UNT_TAKEN.
For example if I place the HTML String in a web page it should show like below for student 100...



HTML String




CATALOG_NBRTERM_DESCR30COURSE_TITLEUNT_TAKENTrimester 1 202473ATitle-110Trimester 1 202474NTitle-210Trimester 1 202479NTitle-320


Appreciate your help on this.

Better to return JSON to the webpage and do the formatting job there…
The HTML formatting is more likely to change at customer's whims than the JSON payload.
HTML formatting option in SqlCL, SQL*PLUS are more targeted at command line jobs.
